# Go - how can i install selenium to use it in go language?

Tags: selenium, go

I am trying to run and test this code but the selenium is missing and i cant install it in my system, what should i do in that case please?

```
ERROR: while execute
test.go:8:2: import "bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium": cannot find package

INSTALL the package i tried:
# apt-get install goisntall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package goisntall
# apt-cache search goinstall
golang-src - Go programming language compiler - source files

CODE: testing
/* Selenium example goinstall bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium */
package yahoo

import (
  "strings"
  "testing"
  "bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium"
)

func TestYahoo(t *testing.T) {
    /* We want firefox, don't care about version much */
    caps := selenium.Capabilities {
        "browserName": "firefox",
    }
    wd, _ := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "", "")
    defer wd.Quit()

    /* Navigate to Yahoo */
    wd.Get("http://www.yahoo.com")

    /* Fill the search box */
    input, err := wd.FindElement(selenium.ByName, "p")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err.String())
    }
    err = input.SendKeys("golang")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err.String())
    }

    /* Hit the search button */
    button, err := wd.FindElement(selenium.ById, "search-submit")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err.String())
    }
    err = button.Click()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err.String())
    }

    /* See that we get expected result */
    source, err := wd.PageSource()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err.String())
    }

    if !strings.Contains(source, "The Go Programming Language") {
        t.Error("Google can't find Go")
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a typo: `apt-get install goisntall`. `goinstall`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, with GOPATH set appropriately,

```
$ env | grep '^GOPATH'
GOPATH=/home/peter/gopath
$ go get -v bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium
bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium (download)
bitbucket.org/tebeka/selenium
$
```

References:

[Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)

[Download and install packages and dependencies](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)